# Printing in CSV format, just like We do in txt format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used to do printing outputs in `.txt` format in python using below code.

`print(Statement,file=f)`  -- f is my file. and it is txt.

When I tried the same with `CSV` format, not working and how to handle this.
I need to print my output one line below the another, (It should start printing from EOF)
Please let me know if some one knows the answer.

Comment: have you tried `csv` module?

Comment: Show what you did. How else do you expect us to diagnose it?

Comment: I am trying to read my own chrome browsing history. and want to save in excel for analysis. i wrote a script to print in .txt format   f=open("history.txt,"a")  and print(history,file=f)  , so no matter whenever i run my script history will append. i tried to do print in file csv, and not working, that is my concern. Hope you understood.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should try using `csv.writer`.

`import csv`

```
with open('thefile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f))
```

Now write your data to file:

```
writer = csv.writer(open("/path/to/your-csv-file", 'w'))
for your-data in data:
    if (Your-Condition):
        writer.writerow(your-data).
```

Try using this. Maybe it would help you and give you your solution.